# Where are Jekyll's %if% statements documented?

Tags: documentation, jekyll

I am looking at a certain Jekyll layout, and I see statements like

```
 {% if page.type == "post" %}
```

I am trying to look on Jekyll's website to find out how exactly are those defined, what all is possible, and so on, and I can't find it.

On [YAML front matter documentation page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/), all I see are some notes about variables. Where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control flow is documented here for shopify liquid](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/control-flow-tags#if). But take care, all shopify tag/filters are not available in Liquid gem.

I have a [small cheat sheet here](http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/tests/) that I try to get up to date with available tag/filters in Jekyll.

Comment: That's it! Well, I am not sure what exactly is "shopify" and how it relates to Jekyll. But that's for another question :)

Comment: I've edited the link to my cheat sheet. Sorry for the bad cut and paste.

Comment: Jekyll uses a number of subsystems which have their own syntax. The Shopify Liquid are the tags that look like `{{...}}` or `{% %}` and are a subsystem to control files and variables. This can be used in all kinds of sources, be it HTML, Markdown or Textile. YAML Frontmatter is another subsystem with a different sytnax, to define variables. Then there are subsystems like the highlighter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be somehow defined on [this webpage - Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers).